# Layout bug manifest on new Area51 home page

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I opened up the new Area51 home page and saw a small layout bug:

[image]

I'm using Chrome 9.0.597.83 beta on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit. (But this is not a Chrome beta bug - I tried it in FF too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks for the report.